# Multiple asynchronous queries to SQL Server under transaction scope

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Trying to run multiple asynchronous queries to SQL Server under transaction scope - it fails unfortunately. Are there any way to make it work? [Unit test](https://github.com/dmitrynogin/sqltest/blob/master/SqlTests/UnitTest1.cs) is on GitHub.

I have a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

With a single record:

```
INSERT INTO [People] ([Name]) VALUES ('John Doe')
```

The test code looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Work()
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
        TransactionScopeOption.Required,
        new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        }))
    {
        var tx = Transaction.Current;
        var name = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            using (var scope2 = new TransactionScope(tx,
                TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                var result = await Task.WhenAll(
                    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                    select QueryAsync());

                scope2.Complete();
                return result[0];
            }
        }).Result;

        Assert.AreEqual("John Doe", name);
    }
}
```

where `QueryAsync` is:

```
const string CS = @"Data Source = .; Initial Catalog = Test; Integrated Security = True;";
const string Select = "WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; " +
    "SELECT [Name] FROM [People] WHERE [Id] = 1;";

async Task<string> QueryAsync()
{
    using (var c2 = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        await c2.OpenAsync();
        var cmd2 = c2.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = Select;
        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        return await cmd2.ExecuteScalarAsync() as string;
    }
}
```

The problem is happening on second connection opening:

> Message: Test method SqlTests.UnitTest1.Should_Work threw exception: 
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has
>   aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException:
>   Failure while attempting to promote transaction. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **There is already an open
>   DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Comment: does it work without the overlapped queries? i.e. something like `var foreach(var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 2)) await QueryAsync();` ? or is concurrency a key part of what you're trying to do here? (note: concurrent queries to a single server often doesn't improve performance)

Comment: Yes, it works synchronously or one by one while being async, but parallel execution is exactly what i am looking here for.